# Number of Chromatids in G1

Tags: dna, dna-replication, replication

I know that in G1, the number of chromosomes is 23 pairs, so 46.

I assumed there were 46 chromatids too.

Why is the number of chromatids in G1 actually 0, not 46?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

These terms are quite similar and, for many, confusing:

- Chromatin
- Chromosome
- Chromatid

But they are not synonyms. According to *Molecular Cell Biology*, Lodish, 4th ed:

> Chromatin: Complex of DNA, histones, and nonhistone proteins from which eukaryotic chromosomes are formed.

Which brings us to:

> Chromosome: In eukaryotes, the structural unit of the genetic material consisting of a single, linear double-stranded DNA molecule and associated proteins.

So, you can think of *chromatin* as the building material of *chromosomes*.

But *chromatid* has a very different definition:

> Chromatid: One copy of a duplicated chromosome, formed during the S phase of the cell cycle, that is still joined at the centromere to the other copy; also called sister chromatid.

So, one should not use the term *chromatid* as synonym of *chromosome*. Chromatid is the name of each copy of the chromosome after the S (synthesis) phase. According to that terminology, there is no chromatid before the duplication.

I have to confess that I personally don't follow that terminology: I like to say to my students that, before S phase, each chromosome has 1 chromatid and, after the S phase, each chromosome has 2 chromatids. Even this not being the most correct terminology, it has some advantages: it makes the student understand that the number of chromosomes **doesn't double** after the S phase.

---

Source:

- [Lodish, H. (2002). Molecular cell biology. 4th ed. New York, N.Y.: Freeman](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21484/)

Comment: Classic example of too many names spoiling the meaning.